# D3.js chart pie rotate with label

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to click on each piece to make this rotation, the problem is that the labels start to misalign. And they should be aligned as in the beginning.

```js
var width = 670,
  height = 400,
  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
  raio = 180,
  active = !active,
  labelr = raio + 30;


const dataStructure = {
  data: [{
      label: 'Lorem Ipsum 1',
      value: 100,
      color: 'green'
    },
    {
      label: 'Lorem Ipsum 2',
      value: 80,
      color: 'red'
    },
    {
      label: 'Lorem Ipsum 3',
      value: 45,
      color: 'blue'
    },
    {
      label: 'Lorem Ipsum 5',
      value: 20,
      color: 'yellow'
    },
    {
      label: 'Lorem Ipsum 6',
      value: 70,
      color: 'orange'
    }
  ]
};


const arc = d3
  .arc()
  .outerRadius(raio)
  .innerRadius(8);

const labelArc = d3
  .arc()
  .outerRadius(radius - 40)
  .innerRadius(radius - 40);


const pie = d3.pie().sort(null).value(100)(dataStructure.data);

const svg = d3
  .select('#chart-d3')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', 450)
  .attr('class', 'container-svg')
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ' ,' + height / 2 + ')');

svg.append('g').attr('class', 'labels');

svg.append('g').attr('class', 'slices');


const key = function(d) {
  return d.data.label;
};

const slice = svg.select('.slices').selectAll('path.slice').data(pie, key).enter();

// gera os 'pedaços' e coloca efeito
slice
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', arc)
  .attr('stroke', '#F0F1F5')
  .attr('stroke-width', '1')
  .style('fill', function(d) {
    return d.data.color;
  })

  .on('click', (d, i) => {

    var rotate =
      110 - ((d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2 / Math.PI) * 180;

    svg
      .transition()
      .attr(
        'transform',
        'translate(' + width / 2 + ' ,' + height / 2 + ') rotate(' + rotate + ')'
      )
      .duration(1000);


    d3.selectAll('text')
      .transition()
      .attr('transform', function(d) {
        var c = labelArc.centroid(d),
          x = c[0],
          y = c[1],
          // pythagorean theorem for hypotenuse
          h = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        return (
          'translate(' + (x / h) * labelr + ',' + (y / h) * labelr + ') rotate(' + -rotate + ')'
        );

      })
      .attr('text-anchor', function(d) {
        return (d.endAngle + d.startAngle) / 2 > Math.PI ? 'end' : 'start';
      })
      .duration(1000);
  });

// label
const text = svg.select('.labels').selectAll('text').data(pie, key).enter();

text
  .append('text')
  .attr('dy', '.35em')
  .text((d) => {
    return d.data.label
  })
  .style('fill', '#47484c')
  .attr('font-family', 'Bradesco Sans')
  .attr('font-size', '14px')
  .attr('font-weight', '500')
  .attr('id', function(d, i) {
    return 'legend-' + i;
  })
  .attr('transform', function(d) {
    var c = labelArc.centroid(d),
      x = c[0],
      y = c[1],
      // pythagorean theorem for hypotenuse
      h = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    return 'translate(' + (x / h) * labelr + ',' + (y / h) * labelr + ')';
  })
  .attr('text-anchor', function(d) {
    // are we past the center?
    return (d.endAngle + d.startAngle) / 2 > Math.PI ? 'end' : 'start';
  });


// d3.select('#circle-icon-0').dispatch('click');
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart-d3"></div>
```

[image: Example]

Code [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hillarykb/w23urbj0/60/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to account for the rotation in the calculation of `text-anchor`. When I fixed that, however, you got jumpy behaviour, since the property is not animatable.

I see some workarounds:

1. Increase `labelr` and use `text-anchor: middle;` consistently, see the example below;

```js
var width = 670,
  height = 400,
  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
  raio = 180,
  active = !active,
  labelr = raio + 45;


const dataStructure = {
  data: [{
      label: 'Lorem Ipsum 1',
      value: 100,
      color: 'green'
    },
    {
      label: 'Lorem Ipsum 2',
      value: 80,
      color: 'red'
    },
    {
      label: 'Lorem Ipsum 3',
      value: 45,
      color: 'blue'
    },
    {
      label: 'Lorem Ipsum 5',
      value: 20,
      color: 'yellow'
    },
    {
      label: 'Lorem Ipsum 6',
      value: 70,
      color: 'orange'
    }
  ]
};


const arc = d3
  .arc()
  .outerRadius(raio)
  .innerRadius(8);

const labelArc = d3
  .arc()
  .outerRadius(radius - 40)
  .innerRadius(radius - 40);


const pie = d3.pie().sort(null).value(100)(dataStructure.data);

const svg = d3
  .select('#chart-d3')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', 450)
  .attr('class', 'container-svg')
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ' ,' + height / 2 + ')');

svg.append('g').attr('class', 'labels');

svg.append('g').attr('class', 'slices');


const key = function(d) {
  return d.data.label;
};

const slice = svg.select('.slices').selectAll('path.slice').data(pie, key).enter();

// gera os 'pedaços' e coloca efeito
slice
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', arc)
  .attr('stroke', '#F0F1F5')
  .attr('stroke-width', '1')
  .style('fill', function(d) {
    return d.data.color;
  })

  .on('click', (d, i) => {

    var rotate = 110 - ((d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2 / Math.PI) * 180;

    svg
      .transition()
      .attr(
        'transform',
        'translate(' + width / 2 + ' ,' + height / 2 + ') rotate(' + rotate + ')'
      )
      .duration(1000);


    d3.selectAll('text')
      .transition()
      .attr('transform', function(d) {
        var c = labelArc.centroid(d),
          x = c[0],
          y = c[1],
          // pythagorean theorem for hypotenuse
          h = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        return (
          'translate(' + (x / h) * labelr + ',' + (y / h) * labelr + ') rotate(' + -rotate + ')'
        );

      })
      .duration(1000);
  });

// label
const text = svg.select('.labels').selectAll('text').data(pie, key).enter();

text
  .append('text')
  .attr('dy', '.35em')
  .text((d) => {
    return d.data.label
  })
  .style('fill', '#47484c')
  .attr('font-family', 'Bradesco Sans')
  .attr('font-size', '14px')
  .attr('font-weight', '500')
  .attr('id', function(d, i) {
    return 'legend-' + i;
  })
  .attr('transform', function(d) {
    var c = labelArc.centroid(d),
      x = c[0],
      y = c[1],
      // pythagorean theorem for hypotenuse
      h = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    return 'translate(' + (x / h) * labelr + ',' + (y / h) * labelr + ')';
  })
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle');


// d3.select('#circle-icon-0').dispatch('click');
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart-d3"></div>
```

2. *If* the label should change position, then calculate the width of the label, and adjust `dx` gradually. When the animation is complete, reset `dx` and set the correct `text-anchor` value. This is more of a hassle of course, but could be a workaround if you really don't want to use `text-anchor: middle`.

```js
var width = 670,
  height = 400,
  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
  raio = 180,
  active = !active,
  labelr = raio + 30;


const dataStructure = {
  data: [{
      label: 'Lorem Ipsum 1',
      value: 100,
      color: 'green'
    },
    {
      label: 'Lorem Ipsum 2',
      value: 80,
      color: 'red'
    },
    {
      label: 'Lorem Ipsum 3',
      value: 45,
      color: 'blue'
    },
    {
      label: 'Lorem Ipsum 5',
      value: 20,
      color: 'yellow'
    },
    {
      label: 'Lorem Ipsum 6',
      value: 70,
      color: 'orange'
    }
  ]
};


const arc = d3
  .arc()
  .outerRadius(raio)
  .innerRadius(8);

const labelArc = d3
  .arc()
  .outerRadius(radius - 40)
  .innerRadius(radius - 40);


const pie = d3.pie().sort(null).value(100)(dataStructure.data);

const svg = d3
  .select('#chart-d3')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', 450)
  .attr('class', 'container-svg')
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ' ,' + height / 2 + ')');

svg.append('g').attr('class', 'labels');

svg.append('g').attr('class', 'slices');


const key = function(d) {
  return d.data.label;
};

const slice = svg.select('.slices').selectAll('path.slice').data(pie, key).enter();

// gera os 'pedaços' e coloca efeito
slice
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', arc)
  .attr('stroke', '#F0F1F5')
  .attr('stroke-width', '1')
  .style('fill', function(d) {
    return d.data.color;
  })

  .on('click', (d, i) => {

    var rotate = 110 - ((d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2 / Math.PI) * 180;

    var rotateRads = rotate / 360 * (Math.PI * 2);

    svg
      .transition()
      .attr(
        'transform',
        'translate(' + width / 2 + ' ,' + height / 2 + ') rotate(' + rotate + ')'
      )
      .duration(1000);


    d3.selectAll('text')
      .attr('dx', 0)
      .transition()
      .attr('transform', function(d) {
        var c = labelArc.centroid(d),
          x = c[0],
          y = c[1],
          // pythagorean theorem for hypotenuse
          h = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        return (
          'translate(' + (x / h) * labelr + ',' + (y / h) * labelr + ') rotate(' + -rotate + ')'
        );
      })
      .attr('dx', function(d) {
        // Will their text-anchor change?
        const oldAnchor = d3.select(this).attr('text-anchor');
        
        // + 2*PI to make it always positive, then modulo
        const newAngle = 
          ((d.endAngle + d.startAngle) / 2 + rotateRads + 2 * Math.PI) % (Math.PI * 2);
        const newAnchor = newAngle > Math.PI ? 'end' : 'start';
        if (oldAnchor === newAnchor) {
          return 0;
        }
        
        if (newAnchor === 'end') {
          return -this.getBBox().width;
        }
        
        return this.getBBox().width;
      })
      .duration(1000)
      .on('end', function(d, i) {
        d3.select(this)
          .attr('dx', 0)
          .attr('text-anchor', function(d) {
          const newAngle = 
            ((d.endAngle + d.startAngle) / 2 + rotateRads + 2 * Math.PI) % (Math.PI * 2);
            return newAngle > Math.PI ? 'end' : 'start';
          });
      });
  });

// label
const text = svg.select('.labels').selectAll('text').data(pie, key).enter();

text
  .append('text')
  .attr('dy', '.35em')
  .text((d) => {
    return d.data.label
  })
  .style('fill', '#47484c')
  .attr('font-family', 'Bradesco Sans')
  .attr('font-size', '14px')
  .attr('font-weight', '500')
  .attr('id', function(d, i) {
    return 'legend-' + i;
  })
  .attr('transform', function(d) {
    var c = labelArc.centroid(d),
      x = c[0],
      y = c[1],
      // pythagorean theorem for hypotenuse
      h = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    return 'translate(' + (x / h) * labelr + ',' + (y / h) * labelr + ')';
  })
  .attr('text-anchor', function(d) {
    return (d.endAngle + d.startAngle) / 2 > Math.PI ? 'end' : 'start';
  });


// d3.select('#circle-icon-0').dispatch('click');
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart-d3"></div>
```